# Page_Load Event Is Executing after a Delay

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have my asp.net web forms application which is hosted on the IIS server. After publishing the website on the production environment i have noticed that the website is very slow, to load a page completely it takes around 8-20 seconds. After debugging the website on the production server i have noticed that after the execution of the Page_PreInit event the debugger takes time (around 5-15 seconds) to start executing the Page_Load event. The same website performs faster on my development PC & development PC IIS.

Note: - The PreInit event is not performing any heavy duty tasks or communicating with sql.

Any suggestions regarding this issue?

Comment: You should check if this behavior is consistent.  Asp.Net application has something called as warm up period, when application initializes all of the required components in memory.  During this time, the processing may be a little slow as compared to later times.

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if it uses it's own application pool.

If it shares a pool with other applications, IIS will reload all of them.